# Unclear mathematical passage with integral and logarithms

Tags: integration

The professor wrote this equality.

$$h(x) = -\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma ^2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}\log_2\left[{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma ^2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}}\right]\,{\rm d}x$$

$$=-\frac{1}{\ln 2} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma ^2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}} \ln\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma ^2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right]\,{\rm d}x$$

$$=-\frac{1}{\ln 2} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\ln\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma ^2}}\right]e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}\,{\rm d}x-\frac{1}{\ln 2} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left[-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right]\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma ^2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}} dx$$

I don't understand why.
Surely it must have used a basic change of the base-2 logarithm to natural logarithm but do not understand how.

Someone could show me the intermediate steps please? I'm going crazy.

Thanks a lot

Comment: From the first to the second line is a change of base from $2$ to $e$ of the logarithm. From the second to the third line is I think a use of  integration by parts for a product of functions.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thanks, yes I knew. The problem is that I don't understand all the steps. I would like to see them written in order to understand better..

Comment: The first step is just $\log_2 x = \ln x /\ln 2$, there's nothing magical about it.

Comment: There is no integration by parts. The second step is just the log-product-rule: $\log(ae^{-b}) = \log(a) + \log(e^{-b}) = \log(a) - b$. These does seem to be a factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}$ missing from the first integral (in the last line) though.

Comment: Thanks orion and thanks Winther, I solved. Thank you very much!